# Context Free Grammar for which a RegEx is impossible

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to find out if its possible to have an example of a CFG for which it is impossible to give a Regular Expression which can accept the same language.

Comment: If you even know a bit about what these two are, the answer should be obvious... come on, did you even try? If so, show us.

Comment: This is obviously a homework question...

Comment: S -> { S } S

S -> ε

A language for balanced parenthesis seems like it would work, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since a regular machine/expression has only a limited (pre-defined) number of states, it cannot "remember" (infinitely) earlier parts of the input.

As such recognizing the following expression is impossible for a state-machine: a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> (n∈ℕ)

You could make such a machine for n ≤ x, where x∈ℕ, but no state-machine can do it for every possible value from ℕ.

Comment: You are saying that a (finite) regular expression can't capture an infinite expression. Which is kind of a moot point, since infinte expressions doesn't exist, and if they did, they would be captured by infinite regular expressions!

Comment: You could make a state machine that accepts $a^x b^x$ where $x=10000$, or $x=1000000$. You could not make a state machine for arbitrary $x$. You could make a stack machine/pushdownautomaton or turing machine that accepts arbitary $x$. See [this link](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dsteurer/toc13/lectures/9/) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Any language which requires **counting/remembering** can't be expressed as a regular expression.

For example, a language which checks balanced parenthesis:

```
S -> { S } S

S -> ε
```