# RegEx to parse nested tags?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have text like this:

```
This is {name1:value1}{name2:{name3:even dipper {name4:valu4} dipper} some inner text} text
```

I want to parse out data like that:

```
Name: name1
Value: value1

Name: name2
Value: {name3:even dipper {name4:valu4} dipper} some inner text
```

I would then recursively process each value to parse out nested fields.
Can you recommend a RegEx expression to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why didn't your attempt work?

Comment: Regex cannot do that.

Comment: What regular expression engine are you using? Some are able to perform recursive matching, but even if possible it's probably easier and more maintainable to do it in code instead.

Comment: To build on SLakes comment... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120170/context-free-grammar-for-which-a-regex-is-impossible

Comment: Regex _can_ do that, just as you can do this with a beowulf-cluster of VIC-20s if you really, really wanted to. It would just be difficult, and not useful past the exercise. You need a stack-based parser, that you could code up faster than figuring out the regexes.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis: No; it is _fundamentally impossible_ to write a regex that can parse unlimited nestings.  (although some extensions to regex can)

Comment: @SLaks unlimited, yes. To parse out what is above, can be done. But should not be. Unless you have an beowulf-cluster of VIC-20s looking for a purpose, I guess.

Comment: @SLaks, it's very possible. See my answer. Note that regex aren't regular. (This isn't formal language theory.)

Comment: @Qtax: That's what I meant by "some extensions to regex".

Comment: @SLaks, well, "some extensions" would be PHP, Perl, C#, VB (not *that* few as your comment suggests). Also, your comment *"fundamentally impossible"* seems to suggest that you're talking about regular expressions in the theoretical sense, which is definitely not what is meant here [on SO]. Nearly all regex implementations can match much more than theoretical regular expressions, not including the ones that support recursive patterns. The pattern `(.)\1` is supported by nearly every modern programming language, yet isn't "regular".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# you can use [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) to count and balance the brackets:

```
{ (?'name' \w+ ) :       # start of tag
(?'value'                # named capture
  (?>                    # don't backtrack
    (?:
      [^{}]+             # not brackets
    | (?'open' { )       # count opening bracket
    | (?'close-open' } ) # subtract closing bracket (matches only if open count > 0)
    )*
  )
  (?(open)(?!))          # make sure open is not > 0
)
}                        # end of tag
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/016JMO):

```
string re = @"(?x)       # enable eXtended mode (comments/spaces ignored)
{ (?'name' \w+ ) :       # start of tag
(?'value'                # named capture
  (?>                    # don't backtrack
    (?:
      [^{}]+             # not brackets
    | (?'open' { )       # count opening bracket
    | (?'close-open' } ) # subtract closing bracket (matches only if open count > 0)
    )*
  )
  (?(open)(?!))          # make sure open is not > 0
)
}                        # end of tag
";

string str = @"This is {name1:value1}{name2:{name3:even dipper {name4:valu4} dipper} some inner text} text";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str, re))
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, value: {1}", m.Groups["name"], m.Groups["value"]);
}
```

Output:

```
name: name1, value: value1
name: name2, value: {name3:even dipper {name4:valu4} dipper} some inner text
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Perl/PHP/PCRE it's not complicated at all. You can use an expression like:

```
{(\w+):         # start of tag
   ((?:
      [^{}]+    # not a tag
   |  (?R)      # a tag (recurse to match the whole regex)
   )*)
}               # end of tag
```

Comment: I am using C#, and I don't believe it supports (?R). It seems I will just need to programmatically solve this, regular expressions won't work.

Comment: @user1044169, in C# you have balancing groups which can be used to get the same result.